Error: Detected multiple instances of Alpine running. ( Livewire 3.x & Laravel 11.x )
When working with Laravel and Liveware in a new installation, it shows that error.

the JavaScript fails, says the OFFICIAL PAGE (Recomendation from official Livewire page), which is because Breeze brings an Alpine, and Livewire brings another Alpine and they collide. You have to eliminate the Alpine that comes with Breeze and only leave the one from Livewire.
These 3 lines of Alpine must be removed from the resources/js/app.js file:


The Livewire installation docs clarify that AlpineJS is bundled with Livewire, so you must not include it yourself as you might have previously done. Thus you must remove that previous method (as per @Rubén Ruíz's answer).
However, that causes a problem for pages which need Alpine but don't have any Livewire components. To get access to Alpine regardless, you can add @livewireScripts on every page, probably in your layouts/app.blade.php template.

I have a similar problem.
But even after removing these lines from the resources/js/app.js. My problem did not solve.
Then after removing these lines, I did this.
I run npm run build to build my assets again. And it worked like a charm.
Here is the detailed solution link:
https://laraveldaily.com/post/livewire-3-laravel-breeze-error-alpine-js-conflict
